# HDF5 error: unable to lock file,Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: c++, hdf5

I have an application which writes a new HDF file at every 100th iteration of a loop.

There is normal output at steps 0, 100, 200, 300, and 400, but at step 500 i get

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.5) thread 0:
  #000: H5F.c line 444 in H5Fcreate(): unable to create file
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Unable to open file
  #001: H5Fint.c line 1567 in H5F_open(): unable to lock the file
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Unable to open file
  #002: H5FD.c line 1640 in H5FD_lock(): driver lock request failed
    major: Virtual File Layer
    minor: Can't update object
  #003: H5FDsec2.c line 959 in H5FD_sec2_lock(): unable to lock file, errno = 11, error message = 'Resource temporarily unavailable'
    major: File accessibilty
    minor: Bad file ID accessed
```

The error happens in the call to `H5Fcreate`.

No matter how many outputs i make before step 500 (e.g. output at every step, or no output at all, or one output at step 499) - all outputs are correct, but at step 500 i get the above error message.

I checked: all HDF files that get created, are closed again immediately after writing.
(all HDF5 calls go through wrapper functions which write to a logfile the handles of the files being created, opened and closed)

Under what circumstances does this error message occur?

Is there a probability to find out what exactly the problem is?

Comment: Does the file already exist? If yes, check the permissions

Comment: @Geoffroy The file indeed existed, but it had permissions "-rw-r--r--". However, when i deleted all files in the output directory prior to runn ing my program, the HDF files were written without complaint. Thanks!